# Dynamic programming min grid path

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Hi I've started coding with dynamic programming, but I always get the error ''int' object is not subscriptable'. I've searched online, but I don't even put an int function in my code. Could someone help please?

```
def minCost(cost, row, col):
    
    # For 1st column
    for i in range(1, row):
        cost[i][0] += cost[i - 1][0]

    # For 1st row
    for j in range(1, col):
        cost[0][j] += cost[0][j - 1]

    # For rest of the 2d matrix
    for i in range(1, row):
        for j in range(1, col):
            cost[i][j] += (min(cost[i - 1][j - 1],
                        min(cost[i - 1][j],
                            cost[i][j - 1])))

    # Returning the value in
    # last cell
    return cost[row - 1][col - 1]
```

Comment: int is not a function but a data type, and you are trying to access an element/index of an integer which doesnt work, Which line gives you this error?

Comment: What is the full traceback? and what is cost it may be that you are passing an int not a dataframe when calling this function

Comment: @JosipJuros the 4th line gives me this error.

Comment: @Patrick cost needs to be a natrix

Comment: Is cost a 2d matrix? can you provide an example please

Comment: I am pretty sure then that cost is not a 2d array but a 1d array, and is breaks when it finds the 2nd bracket, bc you reference an int and  then try to do a [0] on it.

Comment: Please debug your code and check what each of those parameters are

Comment: We are given this example: 
>>> bepaalAantalKortsteRoutes(4,7,[(0,4),(1,2),(3,3)])
18

Comment: Ah so its a homework task makes sense, so which number is what?

Comment: Yes, the assignment is: Write a Python function countNumberOfShortestRoutes that takes as parameters the number n of rows and the number m for columns of the grid, as well as a list of coordinates of blocked positions. The function should return the number of distinct shortest routes from (0,0) to (n-1, m-1)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand which number is supposed to be what in your example but when I copy you function and put these in it as parameters I get an output of 10.

```
cost = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
rows = 4
col = 4
print(minCost(cost,rows,col))

OUTPUT : 10
```

Please maybe elaborate further and make sure your parameters are in the correct format.

EDIT:
also in your example, the matrix you provided and the rows and cols, they dont match. So I do not understand what those parameters represent

Comment: if I put it in Jupyter I also get an outcome, but not on my schools platform..

Comment: @Mioltair Then your school platform has some major issue, From what I understand the rows and cols need to match the dimension of the cost matrix, in your example in the comments above they do not, but both for me and in the other answer they do. Contact your schoolto notify them their tool is broken

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index `cost` in a dimension that doesn't exist. It needs to be 2 dimensional to have 2 indexes:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

You must pass `cost` as the matrix, not `row`.

```
# In this form
minCost([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 2, 3)
```